# spotify api token response code 400

Tags: spotify

I received successfully access code, by providing credentials after get request https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize.

Now I am trying to receive access token by making POST request to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

My java code looks like:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    URIBuilder url = new URIBuilder();
    url.setScheme("https").setHost("accounts.spotify.com").setPath("/api/token")
        .addParameter("code", Spotify.code)
        .addParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8888/callback")
        .addParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    URI buildurl = url.build();
    HttpPost requset = new HttpPost(buildurl);

    String header = new String(client_id + ":" + client_secret);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(header.getBytes());     
    header = new String(encoded);
    requset.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + header);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(requset);
```

After executing request I receive response code 400. 
I have validated request value and header, it looks good.

What am I doing wrong? I suppose response code 400 indicates that something is wrong in my request.

Comment: Does the response come with an error description? That should give you a clue of what's gone wrong.

It's also worth making sure is that the code hasn't been used previously, since attempting to reuse it will return a 400 Bad Request response.

Comment: No description, just ERROR and code number. I tired using code for first time and the same result obtained. Maybe there is some timeout for every code. I am doing separate requests by manually running httpclient - first for receiving code and second for access token.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse an old `code`, or is it the one you are getting immediately before through the `authorize` endpoint?

Comment: It is one I am getting immediately by requesting to authorize endpoint.

Comment: I am having this same problem and think it has to do with the base64 encoding